# Do lycanthropes age faster based on their form?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, shapeshifting, aging, lycanthropy

Many lycanthropes take the form of short lived creatures such as rats. Lycanthropes fully become the animal they change into during the full moon, that is to say all statistics not solely physical statistics. Given that humans can live more than eighty years and rats live only two years; would a Wererats, spending significant time as a rat age much faster than a normal human?

I'm aware that a question was asked about the [ageing of shapeshifted creatures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197942/60557), but that question handled the case where personality is retained. A dragon in human form or a [druid in wildshape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/166094/60557) is wearing the form, and retains their mental statistics and personality. Lycanthropes shapeshifting is called out as special in the *Monster Manual*, so this may be a case of specific beats out general?

A D&D 5e answer is best, but previous editions are acceptable as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No, they don't

As the [answer you linked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197942/60557) explains, natural age is not [one of the statistics that are expressed in the stat block](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138783/75095), and as it is your statistics that change when you change your form, it is not changed when you change your form. It is irrelevant wether you retain your mental ability scores and personality while doing so. This also is no different when you change form with a lycantropes ***Shapechanger*** ability.

Moreover, all the lycantropes in the *MM* contain a variation of following line in their Shapechanger ability (here from wererat - some others also change their AC):

> **Its statistics**, other than its size, **are the same in each form**.

So it is very clear that even if natural maximum age was a statistic (which it isn't), it would not be changed by changing form.

---

As an aside, the entry about Lycanthropes in the *MM* on p. 206 says:

> However, when the full moon rises, the curse becomes too strong to resist, transforming the individual into its beast form - **or into a horrible hybrid form** that combines animal and humanoid traits.

So wererats do not have to spend their time during the full moon in the form of a normal rat (not that it would matter). They can just as well chose to transform into a hybrid form.